# Reason React using js component

Tags: javascript, ffi, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm having trouble with js interop. I'm trying to use a js component [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) like this:

```
// src/interop/Carousel.js
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

export function Carousel(props) {
  return (
    <Slider>
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name} 1</h3>
      </div>
    </Slider>
  )
}


/* src/Carousel.re */
[@bs.module  "./interop/Carousel"] [@react.component]
external  make: (~name: string) =>  React.element  =  "";

/* src/index.re */
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<Carousel  name="ahaha"  />,  "carousel");
```

But met with this error in webpack:

```
ERROR in ./lib/js/src/Index.bs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './interop/Carousel' in '[...]/reason_react_example/lib/js/src'
 @ ./lib/js/src/Index.bs.js 6:15-44
```

So it looks like BS doesn't consider `Carousel.js` file when compile?

btw, I'm following this [reason-react doc](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/components#interop)

Comment: does this file exist? lib/js/src/interop/Carousel.js?

Comment: it doesn't exist

Comment: Well - is that not the problem here?

Comment: hmm, looks like I have to put the file directly into lib/js/src and setup webpack to load jsx

Answer (score 2):

BuckleScript will put the generated js artifacts in `lib/js/...` by default, so you either have to write your imports relative to that, or configure `bsb` to put the artifacts alongside the source files. You do the latter by setting `"in-source": true` for a given `package-spec` in `bsconfig.json`. E.g.:

```json
{
  "package-specs": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "in-source": true
  }
}
```

See the [documentation on the `package-specs` configuration item](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/build-configuration#package-specs).

Answer (score 1):

After some tweaks, here is what works for me:

```
// lib/js/src/interop/Carousel.js
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

const Carousel = props => {
  return (
    <Slider>
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name} 1</h3>
      </div>
    </Slider>
  )
}

export default Carousel


// src/Carousel.re    
[@bs.module "./interop/Carousel"] [@react.component]
external make: (~name: string) => React.element = "default"; // handle default export

// src/Index.re
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<Carousel name="it works!" />, "carousel");
```

Since `Carousel.js` is using es6 and jsx, I need to setup webpack to work with it ([es6](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-env), [jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-react)). And `bsconfig.json` needs to have these settings:

```
"reason": {
  "react-jsx": 3
},
"package-specs": [
  {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "in-source": false
  }
]
```